# Update system seems to be broken

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

Today I went to do my usual `apt update` and `apt upgrade` commands and I ran in an issue. Whenever I enter `sudo apt update`, I get prompted my *password* as usual but then nothing happens. The cursor blinks and then turns stationary, but the update process never starts.

I tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but it didn't change anything. Changing the source server seems to be broken too, and the process of changing keeps freezing the software & update utility.

I run Ubuntu 18.10 with kernel 5.0.5. The issue is still here on 5.0.1 and 4.20.0. Any idea ?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: @Tintin it found a package to autoremove (libllvm:i386) but nothing else. The autoremove did not change anything to my problem

Comment: Try removing `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* ` and then `sudo apt clean && apt update`

Comment: @Tintin Same whole lot of nothing :'( the apt clean did not return anything if thats important

Comment: Since you're not getting any errors that's the main problem.

Comment: @Tintin I guess so yeah. Weird thing is that i dont recall changing anything to trigger this bug, its like it appeared on its own

Comment: what errors do you get? can you post the output?

Comment: @j0h I have 0 errors whats however, thats the problem ! It just hangs. Its not a network problem tho as the rest of the system works just fine

Comment: Do you have anything in `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: I have thought of the same @mikewhatever but that's not the case in here. It's not the problem with the mirrors rather it's something else since it's not showing any errors at all.

Comment: @Bruh post output from `sudo strace apt-get update > log.log 2>&1` it will be in  a file named log.log

Comment: @j0h Ok quick feedback here. Yesterday I tried it with both my home wired connection and wifi and the issue was the same, which made me think it was not network related.
This morning however, I went back on it on my way to work and used my phone's connection. And BOOM 106 hits when entered an apt update... I guess there is something wrong with my network. No idea what since my desktop is also on the network and also running 18.10 and has no problem updating. Thanks for the help anyway !

Comment: @Tintin see the above comment, it seems to be fixed-ish, thnaks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I'll answer my own problem in case other have the same issue I did. Changing network from my local wired connection or wifi to my phone's 4G seemed to resolve the problem, even if the same connection lets my desktop with same config update just fine.
Idk why that is, probably some sort of driver things...