# Can't update from my home network

Tags: networking, updates, update-manager

A month ago, I posted [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130204/update-system-seems-to-be-broken) regarding my laptop apparently freezing when updating on my home network. After prompting for password, nothing would display on my terminal. On any other network though, the computer would update perfectly fine. Not having time to dive more into that, I came to the conclusion that it was a driver issue and that I could be fixed with 19.04, so I waited.

I now have a bit more time to investigate and since switching to 19.04 (using my phone's hotspot) did not change anything im reaching back to you.

First thing I noticed is that the laptop is actually not frozen and is updating... It is just extremely slow.[image]

To give you an idea, this is after waiting about 15 min. Each line took a while to finally appear, and it has been on that last one for an other 10min. After those 10mins, it unstuck itself by ignoring the next `get` stages : 
[image]
It is not a network speed problem, here is the result of a speedtest while the update was running :[image]
Finally, this is not my box blocking the ubuntu server ports because my desktop, also running 19.04 with similar settings (especially as far as the update server to use and stuff) is updating perfectly fine on the same network.

Any idea ? If it can help, the issue is the same with both wired and wifi connections

EDIT : sitrep after 50mins of the update slowly progressing, note the extremely low download speed[image]

EDIT 2 : after research, sources.list is clean and server is not the issue. Here is the result of `sudo strace apt update` :

```
munmap(0x7fd0b81fc000, 2783)            = 0  
close(5)                                = 0  
geteuid()                               = 0  
getegid()                               = 0  
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/kernel/ngroups_max", O_RDONLY) = 5  
read(5, "65536\n", 31)                  = 6  
close(5)                                = 0  
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)   = 0x7fd0b72d2000  
getgroups(65536, [0])                   = 1  
setgroups(1, [65534])                   = 0  
setresgid(-1, 65534, -1)                = 0  
setresuid(-1, 106, -1)                  = 0  
getpid()                                = 5250  
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.9zhf7x", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 5  
unlink("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.9zhf7x") = 0  
close(5)                                = 0  
getpid()                                = 5250  
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.O5IFAd", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 5  
unlink("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.O5IFAd") = 0
close(5)                                = 0  
getpid()                                = 5250  
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.1Rjq4S", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 5  
unlink("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.1Rjq4S") = 0  
close(5)                                = 0  
getpid()                                = 5250  
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.Vl5byy", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 5  
unlink("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.Vl5byy") = 0  
close(5)                                = 0  
getpid()                                = 5250  
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.lV2Y1d", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 5  
unlink("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.lV2Y1d") = 0  
close(5)                                = 0  
setresuid(-1, 0, -1)                    = 0  
setresgid(-1, 0, -1)                    = 0  
setgroups(1, [0])                       = 0  
munmap(0x7fd0b72d2000, 266240)          = 0  
stat("/usr/lib/apt/methods/http", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=174248, ...}) = 0  
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0  
pipe([7, 8])                            = 0  
fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0  
fcntl(6, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0  
fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0  
fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0  
clone(child_stack=NULL,  
flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd0b78e5a50) = 5253  
fcntl(5, F_GETFL)                       = 0 (flags O_RDONLY)  
fcntl(5, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0  
fcntl(8, F_GETFL)                       = 0x1 (flags O_WRONLY)  
fcntl(8, F_SETFL, O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0  
close(6)                                = 0  
close(7)                                = 0  
select(6, [5], NULL, NULL, NULL)        = 1 (in [5])  
read(5, "100 Capabilities\nSend-Config: tr"..., 64000) = 64  
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/auto-apt-proxy", R_OK|X_OK) = 0  
pipe([6, 7])                            = 0  
clone(child_stack=NULL, 
flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, 
child_tidptr=0x7fd0b78e5a50) = 5254  
close(7)                                = 0  
stat("/usr/bin/xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=80224, ...}) = 0  
stat("/usr/bin/zstd", 0x7fffb91cf5f0)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)  
stat("/usr/bin/lz4", 0x7fffb91cf5f0)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)  
stat("/bin/gzip", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=97336, ...}) = 0  
stat("/usr/bin/xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=80224, ...}) = 0  
stat("/bin/bzip2", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=38984, ...}) = 0  
stat("/usr/bin/xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=80224, ...}) = 0  
read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0  
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=5254, si_uid=106, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
close(6)                                = 0  
wait4(5254, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 5254 
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_disco_InRelease", 0x7fffb91cfc60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)  
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_disco_InRelease", 0x7fffb91cfd30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/apt/methods/http", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=174248, ...}) = 0  
pipe([6, 7])                            = 0  
pipe([9, 10])                           = 0  
fcntl(6, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0  
fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0  
fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0  
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0  
clone(child_stack=NULL,  
flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, 
child_tidptr=0x7fd0b78e5a50) = 6110  
fcntl(6, F_GETFL)                       = 0 (flags O_RDONLY)  
fcntl(6, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0  
fcntl(10, F_GETFL)                      = 0x1 (flags O_WRONLY)  
fcntl(10, F_SETFL, O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 0  
close(7)                                = 0  
close(9)                                = 0  
select(7, [6], NULL, NULL, NULL)        = 1 (in [6])  
read(6, "100 Capabilities\nSend-Config: tr"..., 64000) = 64  
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/auto-apt-proxy", R_OK|X_OK) = 0  
pipe([7, 9])                            = 0  
clone(child_stack=NULL, 
flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd0b78e5a50) = 6111  
close(9)                                = 0  
read(7, "", 4096)                       = 0  
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6111, si_uid=106, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---  
close(7)                                = 0  
wait4(6111, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 6111  
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_disco- updates_InRelease", 0x7fffb91cfc60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)  
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_disco-updates_InRelease", 0x7fffb91cfd30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)  
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/auto-apt-proxy", R_OK|X_OK) = 0  
pipe([7, 9])                            = 0  
clone(child_stack=NULL, 
flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, 
child_tidptr=0x7fd0b78e5a50) = 6896  
close(9)                                = 0  
read(7, ^C0x55feeddd9900, 4096)           = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
```

And the output of `ifconfig | grep errors` :

```
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps to investigate the problem**

This might not necessarily be a problem with network.

Try disabling any custom repositories that you've used earlier - if you have any in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. One of them may cause issues.

In case you don't have any custom repositories you can try to use:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

or backup your `/var/lib/apt/lists` and update cache again, like so:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists.bak
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/lib/apt/lists.bak
sudo apt-get update
```

In case the problem persists, try to switch to other ubuntu mirrors using `Applications menu` -> `Updates` -> `Settings` and go to first tab with ubuntu software. Change your download server to the country you're living in or any other.

**OP case solution**

After investigating the apt-get trough strace it was discovered that there is `auto-apt-proxy` package installed on OP's PC. Any kind of proxy may cause problem as such described in OP's question.

Solution was to basicly purge (uninstall) this package and reboot PC.

```
sudo apt-get purge auto-apt-proxy
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. None of the above changed the problem : Deleting sources.list.d didn't make it work. `apt-get clean` did not return anything and did not fix it. Finally, changing the server hangs in `Loading software list` after changing from `Main server` to `Server from France` or `Server for US`.
I even tried to copy paste the sources.list and sources.list.save files from my working desktop. Same result. I'd like to stress out the fact that the very same laptop updates just fine on any other network.
Any other idea ?

Comment: after hanging its is now veryyyyy slowly downloading from the server, so no progress was made :'(

Comment: So maybe it's a network related problem then. In such case, do you have access to the router or modem, related to this network? If so, please try to temporary disable any firewall / packet filtering on this device, or even reset it to factory defaults if this won't break anything for you. Also, there might be something filtering these mirrors on your ISP side, so you can also try to reach your ISP and ask about it.

Comment: what i dont get then is why my desktop with the exact same settings can update perfectly on that same network !

Comment: ok, so maybe another approach, it's very verbose so expect a "matrix" in your terminal, but you may try strace to find out what apt is doing in background. Install strace: `sudo apt-get install strace` and then run update like so: `sudo strace apt-get update`. If it hangs at some point please paste, let's say, 100 last lines of the log, maybe this will tells us something. Also please add your `ifconfig | grep errors` output.

Comment: Ah, you may have trouble installing strace without apt-get working properly, so you may want to avoid apt-get, instead please download .deb file on other machine that works properly, like `sudo apt-get download strace`, copy it using pendrive or something to your laptop, and then install it via `sudo dpkg -i strace.deb`

Comment: Ok strace was already installed. I'll do an edit of the post with the required stuff as a comment wont be big enough to hold everything.

Comment: sorry for the delay, had to redo the formating of the text so it was readable, stackexchange text editor is not the best lol. Not sure but i noticed a few `no such file or directory` so maybe we have a culprit

Comment: don't bother these "no such file", it's common in many applications, but this caught my attention: auto-apt-proxy - I never saw it before, can you try to remove it? `sudo apt-get purge auto-apt-proxy`, also please try to check if you don't have any proxy settings in your APT, `sudo grep -i -rs proxy /etc/apt/`

Comment: I LOVE YOU :D that is indeed what was preventing me to update at normal speeds. After a purge of `auto-apt-proxy` and a reboot, the computer updated as expected. It also noticed me of two packages to be removed via `autoremove` : libmysqlclient20 and mysql-common so I guess the proxy was from mysql... I didnt really understand what it does from the ubuntu manpage, especially why it would prevent me ftom updating only on this network... But hey, it works now lol. THANK YOU SO MUCH :p

Comment: Great, i've edited my ansewer for this solution. I'll be glad if you can mark it as solution :)

Answer (score 1):

We had a long discussion with Comar under his answer which ended up with a fix, so I will sum it up here.

Using `sudo strace apt update` revealed multiple references to something called `auto-apt-proxy` which did not sound familiar to him. I removed it with `sudo apt purge auto-apt-proxy` and double checked for any proxy for `apt` using `sudo grep -i -rs proxy /etc/apt/` which did not return anything after the call to `apt purge`. I then rebooted just in case and ran a regular `sudo apt update` that executed perfectly.

So idk what was this proxy thing (I dont recall ever asking my machine to install such a package) and why it was holding back the update process only on certain network but removing it fixed everything.

Hope this can help someone in the future.